# selenium - find_element_by_name need explanation

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/sebastian/desktop/chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("http://www.python.org")

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("q")

elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Will someone explain why it says find_element_by_name("q") 
When it is supposed to find the search bar. (It works though) I just doesnt understand why "q"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to http://www.python.org, right click the search bar, and choose 'Inspect Element' or something similar. You will see:

```
<input id="id-search-field" name="q" type="search" role="textbox" class="search-field placeholder" placeholder="Search" value="" tabindex="1">
```

Note the `name="q"`.

Comment: ahh, thats why. But one more thing, is it random that name="q", I mean could name be equal to anything?
please note that I have no knowledge about web related languages.

I think maybe a better question would be; 
What is the "id" the "name" and so on for. What indicates each of these things.

Comment: @sebastian Yes, the name could be anything. `q` stands for query and is often used like this, as in https://www.python.org/search/?q=stuff or https://www.google.com/search?q=stuff